# what does ntohl(*(uint32_t*) ...)do?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

```
ip=ntohl(*(uint32_t*)PQgetvalue(result, i, 0));
```

What is the meaning of this code segment?

My guess is that this code takes an input from PostgreSQL database (its type is `uint32_t`) and converts it to IP format (e.g. `192.168.x.x`)

Is my guess correct? If not, what does it mean?

Note: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl:

> The `ntohl()` function converts the unsigned integer netlong from network byte order to host byte order.

Also, could somebody explain what `*(uint32_t*)` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

```
For most queries, the value returned by PQgetvalue is a null-terminated ASCII
string representation of the attribute value. But if PQbinaryTuples() is TRUE,
the value returned by PQgetvalue is the binary representation of the type 
in the internal format of the backend server
```

I guess `PQbinaryTuples` is true there.

`PQGetvalue()` returns a `char *` as per the docs. `(uint32_t *)` will turn that `char *` into a pointer to an unsinged 32 bit integer, the `*` before that will dereference this to get the actual value (an unsigned, 32bit integer), and finally `ntohl` will convert that into a native 32bit integer for the platform, which presumably means that the original storing format is in network order.

If we were to "split" that code, that would give:

```
// Get value from database as a char *
char *in_database = PQgetvalue(result, i, 0);
// Convert the pointer to char to a pointer to an unsigned, 32bit integer
uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *) in_database;
// Dereference that pointer to obtain the actually stored value
uint32_t stored_value = *ptr;
// Turn that value to a native integer for the CPU
uint32_t ip = ntohl(stored_value);
```

Comment: does **presumably means that the original storing format is in network order** mean the type like x.x.x.x?

Comment: No, it means that the original storage of this integer is big endian. For instance, IP `1.2.3.4` is numner `0x01020304`, and in big endian it is stored as `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04`. However, if your CPU architecture is little endian, this same number is "stored" as `0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01`. The `ntoh*()/hton*()` family of functions are here to convert back and forthm from what the host natively understands to what the network requires. On big endian CPU architectures, these functions are basically noops, but not so on little endian architectures.

Answer (score 4):

`ntohl` means "network to host long." It (presumably) converts an integer type from network (big-endian) to host byte ordering. Be careful when using this method, however, if you are unfamiliar with the endianess of your machine. If you have a little-endian machine and use `ntohl` on data which is already in little-endian format (i.e. wasn't sent in big-endian or otherwise) you may have problems.

`*(unit32_t*)` is a casting to a 32-bit unsigned integer pointer (the `(unit32_t*)` part) and then the preceeding `*` is the dereference operator on that pointer.

**EDIT**

Here is a good reference for endianess as pointed out in the comments below by njr: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: The point of the `ntoh*` and `hton*` functions is that you don't need to care about host endianness.

Comment: `ntohl`  converts to the machine's endianness, not to little-endian. What you need to worry about is the endianness of the thing you got, not that of your own machine.

Comment: What if the host also uses big endian ordering?

Comment: i have no idea about endianess. Do you mean it converts 32bit unsigned int to ip format? and why should I be careful, could you explain further?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for this - updated. I have had problems using this method in the past (where things get inappropriately flipped depending on the underlying implementation).

Comment: @tusherity: Maybe you do not need to be careful as per DanielFischer's response (view my updated response though for possible issues). Network byte ordering is big-endian format. Your machine is in one of 3 (in general, probably either big or little endian, though) endianess. Byte order matters so you can translate and understand your data properly.