# Garbage values and Buffers differences in TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

**First question**: I am confused between Buffers in TCP. I am trying to explain my proble, i read this documentation [TCP Buffer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11922/Solution-for-TCP-IP-client-socket-message-boundary?msg=1250358#xx1250358xx), author said a lot about TCP Buffer, thats fine and a really good explanation for a beginner. What i need to know is this TCP Buffer is same buffer with the one we use in our basic client server program (`Char *buffer[Some_Size]`) or its some different buffer hold by TCP internally ?

My **second question** is that i am sending a string data with prefix length (`This is data From me`) from client over socket to server, when i print my data at console along with my string it prints some garbage value also like this `"This is data From me zzzzzz 1/2 1/2....."` ?. However i fixed it by right shifting `char *recvbuf = new char[nlength>>3];` **nlength to 3 bits** but why i need to do it in this way ?

My **third question** is in relevance with first question if there is nothing like TCP Buffer and its only about the `Char *buffer[some_size]` then whats the difference my program will notice using such static memory allocation buffer and by using dynamic memory allocation buffer using `char *recvbuf = new char[nlength];`. In short which is best and why ?

Client Code

```
int bytesSent;
int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;
char sendbuf[200] = "This is data From me";

int  nBytes = 200, nLeft, idx;
nLeft = nBytes;
idx = 0;
uint32_t varSize = strlen (sendbuf);
bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)&varSize, 4, 0);
assert (bytesSent == sizeof (uint32_t));
std::cout<<"length information is in:"<<bytesSent<<"bytes"<<std::endl;
// code to make sure  all data has been sent
  while (nLeft > 0)
{
    bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket, &sendbuf[idx], nLeft, 0);
    if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      std::cerr<<"send() error: " << WSAGetLastError() <<std::endl;
      break;
    }
    nLeft -= bytesSent;
    idx += bytesSent;
}

 std::cout<<"Client: Bytes sent:"<< bytesSent;
```

Server code:

```
int bytesSent;
char sendbuf[200] = "This string is a test data from server";
int   bytesRecv;
int idx = 0;
uint32_t  nlength;
int length_received = recv(m_socket,(char*)&nlength, 4, 0);//Data length info
char *recvbuf = new char[nlength];//dynamic memory allocation based on data length info
//code to make sure all data has been received
while (nlength > 0)
{
    bytesRecv = recv(m_socket, &recvbuf[idx], nlength, 0);

    if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cerr<<"recv() error: " << WSAGetLastError() <<std::endl;
        break; 
    }
    idx += bytesRecv;
    nlength -= bytesRecv;
}

  cout<<"Server: Received complete data is:"<< recvbuf<<std::endl;
  cout<<"Server: Received bytes are"<<bytesRecv<<std::endl;
  WSACleanup();
  system("pause");
  delete[] recvbuf; 
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Check for [`ntohl()`, `htonl()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173441/what-does-ntohluint32-t-do) to manage the message length prefix correctly.

Comment: I know about them(ntohl and htonl()) but do i really need them because my client server is on same windows architecture. Isn't it ?

Comment: They're not necessary running the stuff on the same host, but the purpose of network programming usually is to exchange the data between different hosts.

Comment: Tried but didnt work anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question: I am confused between Buffers in TCP. I am trying to
>   explain my proble, i read this documentation TCP Buffer, author said a
>   lot about TCP Buffer, thats fine and a really good explanation for a
>   beginner. What i need to know is this TCP Buffer is same buffer with
>   the one we use in our basic client server program (Char
>   *buffer[Some_Size]) or its some different buffer hold by TCP internally ?

When you call send(), the TCP stack will copy some of the bytes out of your char array into an in-kernel buffer, and send() will return the number of bytes that it copied.  The TCP stack will then handle the transmission of those in-kernel bytes to its destination across the network as quickly as it can.  It's important to note that send()'s return value is *not* guaranteed to be the same as the number of bytes you specified in the length argument you passed to it; it could be less.  It's also important to note that sends()'s return value does *not* imply that that many bytes have arrived at the receiving program; rather it only indicates the number of bytes that the kernel has accepted from you and will try to deliver.

Likewise, recv() merely copies some bytes from an in-kernel buffer to the array you specify, and then drops them from the in-kernel buffer.  Again, the number of bytes copied may be less than the number you asked for, and generally will be different from the number of bytes passed by the sender on any particular call of send().  (E.g if the sender called send() and his send() returned 1000, that might result in you calling recv() twice and having recv() return 500 each time, or recv() might return 250 four times, or (1, 990, 9), or any other combination you can think of that eventually adds up to 1000)

> My second question is that i am sending a string data with prefix
>   length (This is data From me) from client over socket to server, when
>   i print my data at console along with my string it prints some garbage
>   value also like this "This is data From me zzzzzz 1/2 1/2....." ?.
>   However i fixed it by right shifting char *recvbuf = new
>   char[nlength>>3]; nlength to 3 bits but why i need to it in this way ?

Like Joachim said, this happens because C strings depend on the presence of a NUL-terminator byte (i.e. a zero byte) to indicate their end.  You are receiving strlen(sendbuf) bytes, and the value returned by strlen() does not include the NUL byte.  When the receiver's string-printing routine tries to print the string, it keeps printing until if finds a NUL byte (by chance) somewhere later on in memory; in the meantime, you get to see all the random bytes that are in memory before that point.  To fix the problem, either increase your sent-bytes counter to (strlen(sendbuf)+1), so that the NUL terminator byte gets received as well, or alternatively have your receiver manually place the NUL byte at the end of the string after it has received all of the bytes of the string.  Either way is acceptable (the latter way might be slightly preferable as that way the receiver isn't depending on the sender to do the right thing).

Note that if your sender is going to always send 200 bytes rather than just the number of bytes in the string, then your receiver will need to always receive 200 bytes if it wants to receive more than one block; otherwise when it tries to receive the next block it will first get all the extra bytes (after the string) before it gets the next block's send-length field.

> My third question is in relevance with first question if there is
>   nothing like TCP Buffer and its only about the Char *buffer[some_size]
>   then whats the difference my program will notice using such static
>   memory allocation buffer and by using dynamic memory allocation buffer
>   using char *recvbuf = new char[nlength];. In short which is best and
>   why ?

In terms of performance, it makes no difference at all.  send() and receive() don't care a bit whether the pointers you pass to them point at the heap or the stack.

In terms of design, there are some tradeoffs:  if you use new, there is a chance that you can leak memory if you don't always call delete[] when you're done with the buffer.  (This can particularly happen when exceptions are thrown, or when error paths are taken).  Placing the buffer on the stack, on the other hand, is guaranteed not to leak memory, but the amount of space available on the stack is finite so a really huge array could cause your program to run out of stack space and crash.   In this case, a single 200-byte array on the stack is no problem, so that's what I would use.

Comment: For 2nd question it works by putting `recvbuf[nlength]= 0;` after recv(). Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

You send 200 bytes from the client, unconditionally, but in the server you only receive the actual length of the string, and that length does *not* include the string terminator.

So first of all you don't receive all data that was sent (which means you will fill up the system buffers), and then you don't terminate the string properly (which leads to "garbage" output when trying to print the string).

To fix this, in the client only send the actual length of the string (the value of `varSize`), and in the receiving server allocate one more character for the terminator, which you of course needs to add.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you please have a look  on the code again, i removed the function you suggested for change because that was there by mistake. I have done now like this   `char sendbuf[30]="This is data From me\0" ; ` and  `char *recvbuf = new char[nlength+1]; ` in client and server respectively but still same thing, dont know y ?

Comment: @user3232405 You don't have to manually add the terminator in the string literal in the client, it will be put there automatically by the compiler. But you *do* need to send it (i.e. send `varSize+1` bytes) **or** add it manually *in the server*.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg: Sorry! still didnt work. More importantly can you please throw some light on other questions.

Comment: @user3232405 One question -> One Answer!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm..........I got it now i put this code `recvbuf[nlength]= 0;` after my `recv()`. Thanks!