# What is *(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]?

Tags: c++, c, casting

In some supposed-C++ code I found, I have `buffer` defined as `const void *buffer;` (it's arbitrary binary data that, I think, gets interpreted as a stream of 32-bit unsigned integers) and in many places, I have

```
*(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]
```

where `index` is some kind of integer (I think it was `long` or `unsigned long` and got swept up in my replacing those with `int32_t` and `uint32_t` when I was making the code work on a 64-bit system).

I recognize that this is taking the address of `buffer` (`&buffer`), casting it as a pointer to a `uint32_t`, and dereferencing that, at least based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173495/291280)... but then I'm confused by how the `[index]` part interacts with that or where I missed inserting the `[index]` part in between the steps I listed.

What, conceptually, is this doing?  Is there some way I could define another variable to be a better type, with the casting there once, and then use that, rather than having this complicated expression throughout the code?  Is this actually C++ or is this C99?

***edit:***  The first couple of lines of the code are:

```
const void *buffer = data.bytes;
if (ntohl(*(int32_t *) buffer) != 'ttcf') {
    return;
}
uint32_t ttf_count = ntohl(*(uint32_t *) &buffer[0x08]);
```

where `data.bytes` has type `const void *`.  Before I was getting `buffer` from `data.bytes`, it was `char *`.

***edit 2:*** Apparently, having `const void *buffer` work is not normal C (though it absolutely works in my situation), so if it makes more sense, assume it's `const char *buffer`.

Comment: `buffer[index]` is illegal if `buffer` has type `void *` : a pointer to void may not be dereferenced. Can you check that this is really the code?

Comment: `&buffer[index]` means `&(buffer[index])`.  If `buffer` were of type `const char *` then it is the same as `buffer + index`, i.e. offset the pointer by `index` number of bytes.

Comment: @M.M could very well be a [gcc extension being used here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Perhaps... gcc 4.9.2 issues a warning even using the default options , so OP should have noticed this

Comment: It was `char *` in the original and I tried making it `const void *` because of external factors and it still compiled and ran (clang-llvm on OS X).  I could as easily cast the `const void *` that I'm getting from my external datasource to `char *` instead.

Comment: @Isaac why don't you leave `buffer` as `const char *` ?

Comment: @M.M I definitely could have it as `const char *`, but it would just be an implicit cast from `const void *`, since that's how `data.bytes` is defined.  If having it as `const char *` makes the question clearer or makes it make sense, assume it's `const char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of issues here!  First of all, a `void *` cannot be dereferenced. `buffer[index]` is illegal in ISO C, although some compilers apparently have an extension that will treat it as `(void)((char *)buffer)[index]`.

You suggest in comments that the code originally used `char *` - I recommend you leave it that way. Assuming `buffer` returns to being `const char *`:

```
if (ntohl(*(int32_t *) buffer) != 'ttcf') { return; }
```

The intent here is to pretend that the first four bytes of `buffer` contain an integer; read that integer, and compare it to `'ttcf'`.  The latter is a multibyte character constant, the behaviour of which is *implementation-defined*.  It could represent four characters `'t', 't', 'c', 'f'`, or `'f', 'c', 't', 't'`, or in fact anything else at all of type `int`.

A greater problem is that pretending a buffer contains an `int` when it did not actually get written via an expression of type `int` violates the *strict aliasing rule*. This is unfortunately a common technique in older code, but even since the first C standard it has caused undefined behaviour. If you use a compiler that performs type-based aliasing optimization it could wreck your code.

A way to write this code avoiding both of those problems is:

```
if ( memcmp(buffer, "ttcf", 4) ) { return; }
```

---

The later line `uint32_t ttf_count = ntohl(*(uint32_t *) &buffer[0x08]);` has similar issues. In this case there is no doubt that the best fix is:

```
uint32_t ttf_count; 
memcpy(&ttf_count, buffer + 0x08, sizeof ttf_count);
ttf_count = ntohl(ttf_count);
```

---

As discussed in comments, you could make an inline function to keep this tidy. In my own code I do something like:

```
static inline uint32_t be_to_uint32(void const *ptr)
{
    unsigned char const *p = ptr;
    return p[0] * 0x1000000ul + p[1] * 0x10000ul + p[2] * 0x100 + p[3];
}
```

and a similar version `le_to_uint32` that reads bytes in the opposite order; then I use whichever of those corresponds to the input format instead of using `ntohl`.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get my head around this—`buffer` is an array of bytes from a particular file format (TrueType Collection), or at least, it should be if the first couple of bytes are the characters `'ttfc'` (hence the first check).  The rest are working under the assumption that the byte stream should be interpreted as a sequence of 4-byte chunks and `*(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]` is a (hacky) way to get the 4-byte chunk at an offset of `index` bytes from the start of the sequence.  …

Comment: Yes. It causes undefined behaviour , so you have to choose between relying on UB (and definitely not using  `-O3` - in fact I'd suggest using `-fno-strict-aliasing` compiler switch), or fixing up the code.  Feel free to use `inline` functions or even macros to make the code look tidier if this occurs in many places.

Comment: Assuming `uint32_t` is a reasonable 4-byte type, defining a function like `static uint32_t fourByteChunkInBufferAtOffset(const char *buffer, uint32_t offset)` to basically do what you give in the last code chunk would make sense... although `uint32_t` is probably the wrong type for the offset.

Comment: Use `size_t` for the offset. That would be a good solution; make sure to use `memcpy` in the function body, not the aliasing cast .   The compiler will optimize it. You could use `const void *` as the parameter type.

Comment: @Isaac updated my answer - realized that `memcmp` is a much better solution to the first problem. Also with your inline function there's no need to pass the offset separately, it can just take a pointer and you call it with `buffer + offset`.

Comment: +1 for using `memcmp/memcpy` instead. But do note that strict aliasing and optimization is not the only problem with `*(uint32_t*)&buffer[index]`. It can also break on systems which have alignment restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

Putting parenthesis in place to make the order of operations more explicit:

```
*((uint32_t *) &(buffer[index]))
```

So you're treating `buffer` as an array, however because `buffer` is a `void *` you can't dereference it directly.

Assuming you want to treat this buffer as an array of `uint32_t`, what you want to do is this:

```
((uint32_t *)buffer)[index]
```

Which can also be written as:

```
*((uint32_t *)buffer + index)
```

EDIT:

If `index` is the byte offset in the buffer, that changes things.  In that case, I'd recommend defining the buffer as `const char *` instead of `const void *`.  That way, you can be sure the dereferencing of the array is working properly.

So to break down the expression:

```
*(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]
```

You're going `index` bytes into `buffer`:  `buffer[index]`

Then taking the address of that byte:  `&buffer[index]`

Then casting that address to a `uint32_t`:  `(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]`

Then dereferencing the `uint32_t` value:  `*(uint32_t *) &buffer[index]`

Comment: In your second code, `index` has a different meaning

Comment: I think this makes sense, except that the latter use of `index` is probably something like `index/4` because of the size difference?

Comment: Once you cast the pointer to the proper type, pointer arithmetic adds `index * sizeof(uint32_t)` to the raw value of `buffer` to get the proper index.

Comment: @dbush So if `index` was originally being used on an array of 1-byte values (`buffer[index]`) and now is being used on an array of 4-byte values (`((uint32_t *)buffer)[index]`), wouldn't the values of `index` to get at the same location in the array be different?